# Checking SELinux permissions in Android?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, selinux

Is there a tool that will allow me to check what permissions an application has in a file or folder?

Comment: Use this app
https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2524485
But you have to root your device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a tool in the AOSP /system/sepolicy/tools/sepolicy-check. You need to compile it and run it on the host not on the target, but it will evaluate your allow rules and let you check permission settings.